# Is not-being or is ist not?

Tags: metaphysics, parmenides

We may differentiate the state of being or existence and that of not-being, where the last point is the opposite of the first point, so this last term means to be not existent. Now I try to figure out if not-being is not. 
Does it hold to say that we can't notice something that is not, so since we notice something, not-being is not?

Answer (score 4):

What is "not-being" ? The absence of being or something else ?

See [Parmenides' *Poem*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parmenides/#WayInq) :

> Come now, I shall tell—and convey home the tale once you have heard—/
>
> just which ways of inquiry alone there are for understanding:/
>
> the one, that [it] is and that [it] is not not to be,/
>
> is the path of conviction, for it attends upon true reality,/
>
> but the other, that [it] is not and that [it] must not be,/
>
> this, I tell you, is a path wholly without report:/
>
> for neither could you apprehend what is not, for it is not to be accomplished,/
>
> nor could you indicate it. (Fr. 2)

To inquiry about "what is not" is "a path wholly without report: for neither could you apprehend what is not, [...] nor could you indicate it."

Thus, there is no knowledge, nor way of speaking, about "what is not".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question in case something remained unclear.

Comment: @Rico1990, nothing can't exist since then it'd be something, not nothing.